# Plotting subset of a subset using loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
head(growthMelt)
        Date  Strain Replicate Fluor
1 2016-08-24    42-2   Fluor.I 14.01
2 2016-08-24    42-4   Fluor.I  9.60
3 2016-08-24    42-6   Fluor.I 47.66
4 2016-08-24    42-8   Fluor.I 28.47
5 2016-08-24 Control   Fluor.I 51.61
6 2016-08-26    42-2   Fluor.I 75.78
```

I have 5 strains, each with three fluorescence measurements for each date. I need to make a plot for each one of the fluorescence measurement per strain vs. date. So, ultimately I need to get something like `plot(Fluor~Date)`. I need five plots, one for each strain with lines for the three fluor (`Fluor.I, Fluor.II, Fluor.III`) measurements on each plot.

There is a lot of data so I elected to use for loops to subset and plot. So far I have tried:

```
strains<-unique(growthMelt$Strain)

 fluors<-unique(growthMelt$Replicate)

for(i in strains){
  sub.strain<-subset(growthMelt, Strain==i)
  for (i in fluors){
    sub.flours<-subset(sub.strain, Replicate==i)
    plot(Fluor~Date, sub.flours)
  }
}
```

The resulting plot only displays one Fluor replicate for one strain.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Also, this is my first question on Stack Overflow so please be gentle. :)

Comment: There's only 1 value of `Replicate` in the head of your data, so to make this reproducible you may need to `dput()` more of the data.

Comment: ggplot(growthMelt, aes(x=Date, y = Fluor)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + facet_grid(Strain ~ Replicate)

Comment: Btw its not very sophisticated to use two times the same index [i] within a loop although I think it goes correct in this one

Comment: @HuubHoofs ggplot did the trick. Thank you! I'd still be interesting in learning how to loop this if anyone has suggestions.

Comment: One option to do it with a loop using base graphics you would need to save the graph during each cycle of the loop, otherwise R will overwrite the current graphics device.  If you are unfamiliar with how to save a plot enter `?pdf` or `?png` at the command line

Answer (score 1):

You will only see the last plot because it overwrites the last plot each time. You could therefore try mfrow which makes a matrix.

```
par(mfrow=c(5,3))

strains<-unique(growthMelt$Strain)

 fluors<-unique(growthMelt$Replicate)

for(i in strains){
  sub.strain<-subset(growthMelt, Strain==i)
  for (j in fluors){
    sub.flours<-subset(sub.strain, Replicate==j)
    plot(Fluor~Date, sub.flours)
  }
}
```

Or you could save each plot to a new document (e.g. pdf):

```
for(i in strains){
  sub.strain<-subset(growthMelt, Strain==i)
  for (j in fluors){
    sub.flours<-subset(sub.strain, Replicate==j)
    pdf(paste("Plot_",i,"x",j,".pdf",sep=""))
    plot(Fluor~Date, sub.flours)
    dev.off()
  }
}
```

Or just one big pdf

```
pdf("Plot.pdf")
for(i in strains){
  sub.strain<-subset(growthMelt, Strain==i)
  for (j in fluors){
    sub.flours<-subset(sub.strain, Replicate==j)
    plot(Fluor~Date, sub.flours)
  }
}
dev.off()
```

Or the **ggplot** option:

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(growthMelt, aes(x=Date, y = Fluor)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
  facet_grid(Strain ~ Replicate)

p1
```